# Creating a django model that uses a 3rd party web service as a datasource

Tags: python, django

How do I create a Django model that uses data from a web-service to populate data.

To elaborate.

I have an HTTP service that returns a JSON array of log entries in the format:

```
[
{date:'2007-01-11',title:'log entry 1'},
{date:'2007-01-12',title:'log entry 2'},
{date:'2007-01-13',title:'log entry 3'},
{date:'2007-01-14',title:'log entry 4'}
]
```

The data is retrieved from a web service, lets say http://localhost/logs via an HTTP GET request. Is it possible to have a model like

```
class log (models.Model):
    date = models.models.DateTimeField('Last updated', auto_now=True)     
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

Or would I need to query the service from some kind of controller and pass it to an admin view? If so how do I override the admin controller?

Comment: What for are you going to use that `log` records?

Comment: @vishes_shell i want to display them as an inline view in the admin for a related record. For instance, I have a database model documents, when ever a user views the document, he sees a list of related log events about the document. I retrieve the events about the document via a web service and it returns a json list.

Comment: So it's somehow connected to real database records? So for your example you got Document that have a field `log`, right? And you want to save it as relation_id? If that so, what would be if record gone missing in your 3rd party service? It's quite complicated i think.

Comment: @vishes_shell Yeah, basically I need a way to show information relating to the document that is sourced from a web service as opposed to data from a model.